# Name Does Not Exist in Namespace

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, data-binding, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to bind an Observable Collection to a XAML Interface.
While everything builds and runs as expected, the following code breaks the Designer with the error that the name ... does not exist in the namespace ....

I am running Visual Studio 2012 Premium with Update 1 on a Windows 7 machine.
The same problem occurs in Silverlight and WPF
I ultimately need to implement a solution in Silverlight 5.

```
<Window x:Class="BindingObservableCollection.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:c="clr-namespace:BindingObservableCollection"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <c:NameList x:Key="NameListData"/>
    </Window.Resources>
```

---

```
namespace BindingObservableCollection
{
    public class NameList : ObservableCollection<PersonName>
    {
        public NameList() : base()
        {
            Add(new PersonName("Willa", "Cather"));
            Add(new PersonName("Isak", "Dinesen"));
            Add(new PersonName("Victor", "Hugo"));
            Add(new PersonName("Jules", "Verne"));
        }
    }
```

Comment: are you sure that error is on this xaml only because i cant see Name anywhere in xaml.

Comment: Literally name "..." does not exists in "...."

Comment: The exact error: The name "NameList" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:BindingObservableCollection"

Comment: Perhaps there is something about how the designer in VS 2012 handles Name - Namespace combinations that I do not understand. The code works fine in the XAML Editor and at run time.

Comment: If one would like a complete example of the type of problem that I am having the project here on Code Project presents the same problem.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/178011/Sorting-an-Observable-Collection-using-the-View-Mo

Comment: I tested and this worked for me.  Try Clean Rebuild

Comment: Thank You! Perhaps it is something with my system.